# c++ compiles to portable assembly?

Tags: c++

All the generated binaries seem to be only OS dependent, and not hardware dependent.

I thought the assembly for each cpu was different, which would mean you have to compile for each diffrent cpu type.

So then why is there compatibility?

Comment: What makes you think it's not CPU-dependent?

Comment: C++ does not compile to 'portable assembly', and indeed 'portable assembly' is a contradiction in terms. If that isn't the answer to your question, please clarify what your question actually is.

Comment: Windows and Mac tried to hide CPU differences in the past, but that's less relevant today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question appears completely unclear: (cross-)complied binaries are of course OS/Machine dependent.

> *"so then why is there compatibility?"*

At the portable language level (plain standard c++ functions and classes), you can compile your code to run on various OS/machine architectures.

This doesn't mean you just can copy artifacts compiled for a particular OS/machine environment to another one without recompiling from source there (or using a cross-compiler).